# Interpreting Linear model coefficients for either Normalised (i.e. Min/Max Scaling) or Standardised (i.e. zero mean unit standard deviation) inputs?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, linear

I have a Linear Regression model that I have fitted on a set of features **X** to a predictor variable **y**. The features and the predictor variable have been normalised using Min/Max scaling. I'm trying to determine from the model which coefficients have the biggest impact on the predictions of **y** (i.e. the model coefficients with the largest magnitude).

Is it possible to do this using data which has been normalised in this way, or should the data have been standardised to zero mean and unit variance before fitting the model?

If **X** should have been standardised, then can I standardise the model coefficients by multiplying them by the standard deviations of the normalised **X**.

Comment: This doesn't sound answerable until you provide some sense of what you mean by "impact on predictions."  You can find *many* threads here asking such questions, so they would be worth researching.